# Handling space constrained interfaces with many meta data options

Tags: design-patterns, contextual-menu

I have the equivalent of a timeline with individual objects that can have many options.  The issue is that the visual representation must remain constrained to easily read the timeline.  The current plan would have a flag to indicate if advanced settings were set for a particular item so that the user can contextually view that information.

The problem arises with the user who needs to build the timeline, they need a way of inserting the meta data.  Some options are simple toggles, feature on/off, which is easily handled in a context menu.  However some require entering values in.  There are examples (few and far between) of context menus that have form elements in them.

For example, Microsoft uses an additional context menu above the regular context menu for font controls.  This includes a dropdown and input which control font and font size.  This meta data about the font and size is viewable and modifiable from the context menu.

[image: Example of Context menu with form elements]

Other examples could be Adobe Photoshops use of Pallet (windows or docked) that provide the form out of context from the selected object. (this however requires objects to support being selected)

**Summary of the Question:**
How best to solve for entering in a large number of options when the interface is restricted from having a large form present.

Comment: Do you have any particular question about the menus?  Requests for examples aren't a very good fit for this site.

Comment: @3nafish I phrased my question to be generic rather than.  Hey guys in this one case that is only useful to me, what should I do. I fail to see on a UX site, looking for supporting examples/research on an existing pattern isnt a very good fit for the site.  Do you have a suggestion on how to rephrase without making the question simply about my situation.  I simply am looking for best practices, usability pit-falls, etc.  Happy to rephrase, but this site should support questions on, here's a pattern, what are the pros and cons (with support).  What are successful and anti-patterns for it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/can-we-broaden-the-area-between-too-narrow-and-too-subjective/1313#1313) by JonW on meta.  The short form is: the site's not just a UX site, it's a UX Q&A site and requests for examples don't usually work well in a Q&A format because there's no one best answer.

Comment: As to how you could improve the post...instead of asking explicitly for examples, ask for the best practices regarding a particular aspect of the design (basically what you just said in your comment).  Good answers will use examples to support their arguments, but it's not really examples you want: it's the pros and cons (again from your comment) that those examples are being used to demonstrate.  Contextual menus for text are a big topic.  Ask about the best practices concerning some particular aspect of them (such as how many elements to include, how to label them, or how to position them).

Comment: @3nafish, Thanks for the constructive suggestions, though I would argue that Patterns are a description of a best practice, but I can take that debate to meta if I so feel the need.  I will attempt to re-word the question later today.

Comment: If you have 7 questions, you should put them in 7 posts!  (Incidentally, Numbers 3, 4, and 7 are still asking for lists.  Number 6 is a good question.)

Comment: @3nafish Can you point me to where lists are verboten?  Having some answer, "Generally simple form elements, such as text inputs and dropdowns works well do to the size constraints of a context menu..." yes does list out the type of inputs as that is necessary, however the question isn't saying, hey list all the types of cookies you like.  The whole concept of best practices is a list.  At this point if the question format gods feel like closing the question then, fine, I can debate the issue on meta.

Comment: I don't know of lists being explicitly forbidden anywhere.  They just tend to get closed because they have no one right answer (which doesn't work very well for a question-and-**answer** site).  They tend to be too general to really be useful for anyone.  For example, "what form elements work best in context menus?" depends entirely on the *context* of those context menus; if User A makes a list based on experience with a desktop publishing site, only some parts of that list might apply to User B's webapp for sketching.

Comment: I like the current form of the question.  Now it's concrete and answerable, and will lead to a set of best practices for a known context. +1

Comment: Chris, is your interface geared at expert or novice users? Putting everything in context menus turns heavy editing into a clickfest. If you are constrained by screen real estate it may be wise to revise the idea of having both timeline and metadata editor on screen at the same time (i.e. are you sure a user needs to see the big picture while editing an object?).

Comment: Geared to more adv users (Data previously got in via XML before the timeline builder was made).  The interface also walks users how to right click to access the existing options.  We are now adding in more complex options, hence the question.  The click-fest is also reduced by a duplicate option.  The point of the builder is to create the timeline, sort the objects, set time, and set the advanced options.  Having separate screens would seem to make it harder to use as context is important.  Additionally think more video timeline, less facebook timeline, though potentially both share the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions.

**1**. Create space for creating or editing an item. Fold out space inside the timeline, or create a modal on top.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsshwg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**2**. Put the UI for editing the advanced options in a modal that is triggered from one of the options in the context menu. This creates a bit of space so that UI can breathe, and you don't have to be afraid of accidentally closing the context menu.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftYBLf.png)</sup>